# A set with custom comparison functor, predictable in case of equality

Tags: c++, set, comparison, key

I'm trying to build a `std::set` with a custom ordering to store "tasks" inside, and I'm wondering wether or not it'll be possible to get what I need with a plain `std` container.

The set is like:

```
std::set<Task*, CompareTasks> taskList;
```

And `class Task` has a public `double priority` member.

What I need:

- EDIT: each task `Task *` must be unique within the `taskList`
- the tasks must be sorted in decreasing `priority`.
- if `task2` happens to share the same `priority` with `task1` already in the list, then "*first come first served*": `task2` must be inserted *after* `task1`.

I tried with the functor:

```
class CompareTasks
{
public:
    bool operator()(Task* const& a, Task* const& b)
    {
        return a->priority < b->priority;
    }
};
```

But tasks I then insert, that have an already recorded `priority`, are just.. not inserted at all. And I thus suspect that the keys of `taskList` are the priorities themselves and not the pointer values `Task*` as written in `std::set<Task*, CompareTasks>`. How can I check whether it's the case?

More dramatically: Since the ordering must be **weak** in creating comparison functors for `std` containers, is there any way I'll be able to achieve this with only `std::set`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition of equivalence for `std::set` when you supply a comparer is `!comp(a,b) && !comp(b,a)`. With your comparison function, you won't be able to insert two `Task *`s with the same priority, because they are equivalent by that definition.

What you want is `std::multiset` - in particular, C++11 `std::multiset`, because its `insert()` has this guarantee not included in C++03 ([ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/insert); this is required by §23.2.4 [associative.reqmts], Table 102 of the standard):

> If the container has elements with equivalent key, inserts at the upper bound of that range.

This means that the newly inserted element will always be after the equivalent elements that are already in the container.

Note that the standard ordered associative containers sort in non-descending order, so you'll need to change your functor if you want tasks sorted by decreasing priority.

Comment: Ok great, this is a nice garantee from C++11, I'll try with a multiset. Thank you! ^ ^ I'm just wondering now about the very *keys* of this `std::set<Task*, CompareTasks>`: they should be pointers to tasks and not priorities, right? Then two different `Task` with the same `priority` should have two different `Task *` addresses and thus not be considered as "replicated".. What's wrong with this reasoning?

Comment: Okay I think it's getting clearer: they *do* have different keys but they are considered as "equivalent" anyway because of this comparer I have supplied.. tricky trick :P

Comment: Okay, it does work now with a multiset, but I feel like I've lost something during the battle: How do I make sure now that the same `Task *` is not inserted twice in the `std::multiset<Task*, CompareTasks> taskList`? Do I have to handle this myself? That was the whole point of using a simple `std::set` in the first place.. :\

Comment: @Iago-lito if you use `multiset` then you'd have to track duplicate pointers yourself (can be as easy as maintaining a `std::set<Task *>` with no custom comparer alongside it). The problem with using `set` is that you'd need to  get your comparer to somehow be aware of the time-of-insertion, which is tricky.

Comment: Very true. I actually was realizing that tracking duplicate pointers wasn't that difficult at all with `multiset` (I just had to add a `bool sent` member to my `class Task` that is checked each time and turns to `true` if the task has been sent to the list, `false` when removed). So it finally works.. perfectly! Thank you again T.C. :)